# Subscribing to a nested observable inside another observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs, nested, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a behaviour subject which holds an observable of some data.
i.e.

```
BehaviorSubject<Observable<data>>
```

How can I subscribe to the nested observable directly?

Comment: `myBehaviorSubject.value.subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just pipe it to one of [the flattening operators](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/), like `mergeMap`:

`yourSubject.pipe(mergeMap(v => v))`

My example:

```
const t = timer(0, 500).pipe(take(5));
const s = new BehaviorSubject(t);
s.next(t);
s.pipe(mergeMap(v => v)).subscribe(console.log);
s.next(t);
s.next(t);
```

Comment: Actually this operator has some side effects, isn't there a pure flattening operator?

Comment: @arcrub What side effects do you experience? And what is a _pure_ flattening operator? It's probably the best to ask another question referring to this answer and explaining problems that you experience.